# Shopware backend and Extjs - Opening detail window

Tags: shopware

I am watching the Shopware video tutorials, and now I am in the part to learn how to open the detail window for a backend custom plugin, but not sure if the guy in the video forgot to mention something but at the end it didn't work for me. I also downloaded the zip and installed it in my local installation and curiously it didn't open the detail window neither. So this guy definetly forgot to mention something.

Here you can find the tutorial and zip to download if you want to take a look: https://www.udemy.com/shopware-developer-training-advanced-english/learn/v4/t/lecture/9724544?start=77

Anyways, does anybody know what is the specific part/code which opens the detail window? I have compared three times my code with the other and can't see the error.

I would appreciate any guidance,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly detail you want to open, but code should looks like this:

```
Shopware.app.Application.addSubApplication({
    name: 'Shopware.apps.Article', //Shopware.apps.Customer or Shopware.apps.Order
    action: 'detail',
    params: {
        articleId: 1 // there is articleId
        //customerId: 1
        //orderId: 1
    }
 });
```

I have created for you example plugin. 
It isn't best practice, but there you can see how work logic: [GitHub](https://github.com/shopwarrior/OssBackendGrid/tree/master/Resources/views/backend/oss_backend_grid/view/list)

If you want to understand deeper - you need to read about [Associations](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/backend-components/associations/).

Created another [sample plugin](https://github.com/shopwarrior/OssArticleInjection) for you, where you can see how to extend Article Detail Window, inject additional field and manage data for this field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am creating a custom plugin where I can open a listing window, where I can see a list of stuff so each item in that list has a pen icon where you can click it to open a detail window with info about the related item.

Comment: @DanielSoublett, I have updated answer, check it please, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, your link helped a lot to understand better. And finally I could open the detail window with the database info in it. Taking advantage of this, do you know an article where I could read to be able to update the info in that detail window? I mean, let's say I have a "name" field, and I want to change the name so after clicking the save button, it should save the new name in the database. Any article talking about that would be appreciated, because I have been searching for it but no luck. Thanks

Comment: @DanielSoublett I have sent you link to shopware dev documentation. You can fine there everything. I don't know what detail window you want to use, do you want to extend some default shopware extJs detail window and add some element? Then you need to check parent script there you can see all event handlers and you can extend and change logic.